# Perl -V description required

Tags: perl

The command for finding the perl version "perl -V" gives information related 
Platform, Compiler, Linker and Libraries, Dynamic Linking, Compile-time options & Locally applied patches. Could you please let me know from where each of these information's are extracted(Environment variables or any other method) and description of various parameters under each group.
I am facing problem in library files inclusion because of many version of Perl installed in my machine.

Below is the description I got from my machine:

Summary of my perl5 (revision 5 version 10 subversion 0) configuration:

```
   Platform:
        osname=MSWin32, osvers=5.1, archname=MSWin32-x86-multi-thread
        uname=''
        config_args='undef'
        hint=recommended, useposix=true, d_sigaction=undef
        useithreads=define, usemultiplicity=define
        useperlio=define, d_sfio=undef, uselargefiles=define, usesocks=undef
        use64bitint=undef, use64bitall=undef, uselongdouble=undef
        usemymalloc=n, bincompat5005=undef
    Compiler:
        cc='gcc', ccflags =' -s -O2 -DWIN32 -DHAVE_DES_FCRYPT  -DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTE
    XT -DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -fno-strict-aliasing -DPERL_MSVCRT_READFIX',
        optimize='-s -O2',
        cppflags='-DWIN32'
        ccversion='', gccversion='3.4.5', gccosandvers=''
        intsize=4, longsize=4, ptrsize=4, doublesize=8, byteorder=1234
        d_longlong=undef, longlongsize=8, d_longdbl=define, longdblsize=12
        ivtype='long', ivsize=4, nvtype='double', nvsize=8, Off_t='long long', lseek
    size=8
        alignbytes=8, prototype=define
      Linker and Libraries:
        ld='g++', ldflags ='-s -L"C:\strawberry\perl\lib\CORE" -L"C:\strawberry\c\li
    b"'
        libpth=C:\strawberry\c\lib
        libs= -lmsvcrt -lmoldname -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lcomdlg32
    -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -lnetapi32 -luuid -lws2_32 -lmpr -lwinmm
     -lversion -lodbc32 -lodbccp32
        perllibs= -lmsvcrt -lmoldname -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lcomdl
    g32 -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -lnetapi32 -luuid -lws2_32 -lmpr -lw
    inmm -lversion -lodbc32 -lodbccp32
        libc=-lmsvcrt, so=dll, useshrplib=true, libperl=libperl510.a
        gnulibc_version=''
      Dynamic Linking:
        dlsrc=dl_win32.xs, dlext=dll, d_dlsymun=undef, ccdlflags=' '
        cccdlflags=' ', lddlflags='-mdll -s -L"C:\strawberry\perl\lib\CORE" -L"C:\st
    rawberry\c\lib"'


    Characteristics of this binary (from libperl):
      Compile-time options: MULTIPLICITY PERL_DONT_CREATE_GVSV
                            PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT PERL_IMPLICIT_SYS
                            PERL_MALLOC_WRAP PL_OP_SLAB_ALLOC USE_ITHREADS
                            USE_LARGE_FILES USE_PERLIO
      Built under MSWin32
      Compiled at Apr 30 2009 14:30:10
      %ENV:
        PERL5_INCLUDE="C:\Perl\lib\CORE\"
        PERL5_LIB="C:\Perl\lib\CORE\"
      @INC:
        C:/Perl/lib
        C:/Perl/site/lib
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [Config](http://perldoc.perl.org/Config.html).

> The Config module contains all the information that was available to the Configure program at Perl build time (over 900 values).

You can query the value of an individual variable. E.g.,

```
C:\> perl -V:intsize
```

Now, if you have multiple Perl installations on Windows, you need to be careful. I have six separate versions on my machine. At some point, I decided to use the ActiveState distribution as the "system" one. Therefore, my path starts with the `bin` directories of that distribution:

```
Path=c:\opt\perl\site\bin;c:\opt\perl\bin; ...
```

The other ones live in their own directories. I have batch files for all of them. These batch files simply prepend the relevant `bin` directories to the path. I can also explicitly invoke them by path. E.g.,

E:\Home> c:\opt\strawberry-5.12.1\perl\bin\perl -V

In addition, I use [Console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) which enables me to open `cmd.exe` shells in tabs with the correct settings for each tab. Finally, I used [FileMenu Tools](http://www.lopesoft.com/en/fmtools/info.html) to set up right-click short cuts to open command prompts with the relevant settings applied.

This way, I can use one main Perl for day-to-day development and other versions are available as needed. And, none of them tramples on each other's toes.

Keep in mind that, while it does not seem to be absolutely necessary, you should set up each distributions `cpan` to use a version specific directory.

Comment: Is the updating of environment variable only way from which one can change the library path include? (As in the above description)

Comment: Exactly what do you want to do? The output of the "perl -V" command cannot be changed. It's set when the program is compiled. You can use -I to specify directories you want to include for Perl modules, and you can set PERL5LIB to specify the directory path of Perl libraries to load. Is that what you want? Try running 'perldoc perlrun' from the command line (if you have the Perl binary in your executable path, it should work). This will give you the command line options for Perl and what they're used for.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Perl?

```
use Config;

print "Perl version: $Config{api_versionstring}\n";

# Same thing:

print "Perl version: $Config{api_revision}.$Config{api_version}.$Config{api_subversion}\n";

# Same Again...

print "Perl version: $Config{PERL_REVISION}.$Config{PERL_VERSION}.$Config{PERL_SUBVERSION}\n";
```

The problem is that earlier version of Perl (somewhere around 5.5) had a decimal number. Therefore, you need to check `$Config{PERL_REVISION}` to see if it is a decimal number or a floating point number.

Take a look at the at [Config module documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/Config.html) Somewhere in there, you'll find everything you need to know. The biggest issue I have is that it's hard to know exactly what you're looking for. It'd be nice if they put some of the more common ones together in one place.